# Difference between simple, continuous and perfect passive participles?

Tags: participles, passive-voice

1. **Surrounded** by people, the musicians stood up.
2. **Being surrounded** by people, the musicians stood up.
3. **having been surrounded**  by people, the musicians stood up.

(A).What are the differences/meanings between the above participle clauses?

(b).When to use simple passive participles(Surrounded) and continuous passive participles(Being surrounded)?

Comment: 1) doesn't necessarily imply any connection between being surrounded and standing up - they just happened at the same time. 2) implies the musicians decided to stand up *because* they were surrounded. 3) might be the same as 2, or might imply the people surrounded the musicians *in order to* get the musicians to stand up.

Comment: Don't (1),(2) and (3) express a similar meaning?

Comment: Obviously the meanings are *similar*, since in all cases the central information is the musicians were surrounded ***and*** they stood up. We're just talking about possible different *nuances / shades of meaning / implications* of the different phrasings.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with FumbleFingers.  I want to add that
1) It is a static status.
2) It is a dynamic process, emphasizing that the "surrounding" is ongoing. 
3) It emphasizes that the process has been done.  When musicians stood up,  musicians have been completely surrounded, in which "surrounding" process has been complete.